# Allow multiple choices in select widget of ng-admin

Tags: angularjs, rest, select, ng-admin

I am conceiving an admin panel for my rest backend. I used the AngularJS admin GUI called ng-admin.

I would like to allow users choosing multiple choices and send them to my rest application.

```
nga.field('languages', 'choice')
    .choices([
        { value: '1', label: 'Choice 1' },
        { value: '2', label: 'Choice 2' },
        { value: '3', label: 'Choice 3' },
        { value: '4', label: 'Choice 4' },
    ])
```

The config code above does only allow one choice. I would like to keep the enhanced widget of ng-admin and not change it with the traditional checkboxes.

Comment: Please provide info of what `ng-admin` is and that you are working on a angular application, if so. I think you need a `multiple` property set on your `select` html tag.

Comment: I added some stuff in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be u want to use [choices](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/src/javascripts/ng-admin/Crud/field/maChoicesField.js) instead of [choice](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/src/javascripts/ng-admin/Crud/field/maChoiceField.js) for multiple selection, references to Git sources.